# JHipster - Issue Deploy Jhipster Registry in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I am working with a Microservices App with JHipster and I want deploy it in AWS Beanstalk. I had tried in diferent ways deploy it the Registry in AWS Beanstalk but it was unsuccessfully. The Registry does not start, not work and it not connect with the microservices.

When I run the app locally, all works fine, It just happen when I deploy it on AWS Beanstalk.

I had tried and looked for all diferent ways to solve it, but I can not find de problem with de Registry. I had tried these solutions without success:

- Change the Ngix port(5000,8081)
- Verify the Maven Package to Production
- Configure the Security Group on EC2 Instance
- Open all ports in EC2 Instance

It is the log:

```
<i>2017-05-04 14:25:51.705 ERROR 25337 --- [et_localhost-15] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Network level connection to peer localhost; retrying after delay

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48)
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116)
at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:71)
at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:187)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple problems deploying jhipster registry on Aws EB. At last I tried deploying it as a docker image. Try this steps

1. Do mvn package docker:build
2. Copy the DockerFile and the war file to a folder and select both the files to create a zip file
3. Go to EB-Select Docker as the web server from the dropdown with single
   instance (Jhipster recommends single instance for jhipster-registry so avoid load balancer)
4. **If you're using VPC then make sure you select at least one public subnets (It took me days to figure out this step)** ref: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-single-instance.html)

Comment: @PeterSmith I have tried the deploy with Docker but I get this issue: 

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.10:build (default-cli) on project jhipster-registry: Exception caught:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed:Connection refused: connect ->[Help 1]`

Comment: If your question to me then Ignore the exception. Just follow the steps above. All you need is the Dockerfile and the war file in a zip folder that should be deployed in the Elastic Beanstalk.